# Deciphering old handwriting

Tags: translation, german-to-english, handwriting, blackletter

Is there anyone that can please decipher the following handwriting and give a brief summary in English?

[image]

Comment: Looks like an entry in a church's log. Someone was baptized

Comment: To all the close-voters: Please notice that deciphering old hand-writings is on-topic (see: [Sind Fragen über die Entschlüsselung von Schriften (auch Handschriften) on-topic?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/sind-fragen-%C3%BCber-die-entschl%C3%BCsselung-von-schriften-auch-handschriften-on-topic/1276#1276)

Comment: @Arsak As originally asked the question was purely a **translation** request. It still is primarily a translation request: presumably a German transcription of the handwriting is not what OP wants. Or does a translation request  become on-topic just because the text is handwritten?

Comment: @PiedPiper I am assuming that non-Germans are not necessarily aware of the differences between historical and modern German handwriting, and of the difficulties even native speaker have with the old handwriting. Hence, non-Germans probably won't ask for a deciphering, although this is the first and crucial step to what they actually want in the end, and this step definitely needs some expertise in German language. And if the difference isn't clear from the question, it should be edited to make it clear, not just closed without any comment, IMHO

Answer (score 3):

Side notes:

- I'll expand abbreviated words in round brackets ( )
- I'll add my own remarks  in square brackets [ ] - some details are still missing [...], I'm open to suggestions here :)

### left column

> 24 Octbr. (Oktober)
>   [...] Bross[ak/ock?]

This is the date and (in a different lettering) probably the name of either

- the place/parish or
- the documenting person

The header of that table should be clear on this.

### right column

> getauft des Maurer Joseph Werner [...] seiner Ehefrau
>   Louise geb. (geborene) Hoffmann am 22/ zwei u (und) zwanzigsten Octbr (October)
>   Nachmittags 1/2 4 u (und) 3/4 4 Uhr [ass.?] geb. (geborenen) Zwillingsmädchen
>   mit Namen:
>   I. Emma Anna
>   II. Martha Bertha
>   Ptn. (Paten):
>   I. Jungfer Anna Winkler Bauerngutsbesitztochter in Heinersdorf
>   II. Frau [N...] Johanna Siegert in Obersdorf - Bauerngutsbesitzer Julius Hoffmann in Beerwalde

Which roughly translates to:

> baptised to the brick layer / mason Joseph Werner [...] his wife
>   Louise nee Hoffmann at October 22nd
>   in the afternoon half past three and quarter to four [...] born twin girls with the names:
>   I. Emma Anna
>   II. Martha Bertha
>   God parents:
>   I. spinster Anna Winkler squire's/land tenure's daughter [not sure about the proper English term]  in Heinersdorf
>   II. Mrs [probably her job/title] Johanna Siegert in Oberstorf - squire/land tenure Julius Hoffmann in Beerwalde

Comment: Ein paar Vorschläge: 1. "getauft **des**", 2. das vor "seiner Ehefrau" kann kein "und" sein, 3. bei den Paten: "Bauerngutsbesitzer", 4. linke Spalte "24 Octbr (??) Brosso<?>. tbc

Comment: @IQV Danke für die Hinweise! Bauern-gutsbesitzer macht natürlich am meisten Sinn. Allerdings war/bin ich mir unsicher, weil ich zwischen *Bau* und *gut* nur zwei Buchstaben erkenne. Was meinst Du? Könnte das auch *Bauergut* heißen? [Scheint zumindest keine ganz unbekannte Schreibweise zu sein](http://wiki-de.genealogy.net/G%C3%BCteradressbuch_Schlesien_1873/Bunzlau#Birkenbr.C3.BCck.2C_Bauergut_in)

Comment: Den Begriff habe ich im [Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutsbesitzer) gefunden. Das zweite Vorkommen ist tatsächlich ziemlich geschludert, im ersten Vorkommen kann ich aber alle Buchstaben erkennen.

Comment: Brossak vielmehr Brossock?!

Comment: Bauerngutsbesitzer, für mich ist das kein B am Anfang.

Comment: @IQV Dann betrachte ich das mal als bestätigt, danke!

Comment: @Thomas *Bauerngutsbesitzer, für mich ist das kein B am Anfang*: Den Kommentar verstehe ich leider nicht - stimmst Du mit der Entschlüsselung "Bauerngutsbesitzer" überein oder nicht (weil es nicht mit B anfängt)? Und falls nciht: was wäre Dein Vorschlag, bzw. welchen Buchstaben siehst Du da?

Comment: Da ist ein "L", den Rest wage ich nicht fest zu legen, aber ja, Bauer... ist das definitiv nicht.

Comment: @Thomas Du hast recht, wenn man den Buchstaben mit dem ersten bei "Beerwalde" vergleicht. Aber das originale Sütterlin-B sieht tatsächlich so aus, da ist eher das von "Beerwalde" untypisch.

Comment: Ja, habe auch "nur" verglichen, glaube aber kaum, daß die Schreibung derart variieren kann. Vor dem u dann sind m.E. mindestens zwei weitere Buchstaben.

Comment: Wobei, wenn ich mir das Sütterli B so anschaue, hast du Recht, aber ist schon komisch, daß dann zwei Schreibweisen benutzt werden. Aber vlt. liegt das auch an dem fest stehenden Begriff, der sich dahinter verbirgt und für andere B - Begriffe wird das neuere benutzt?!

Comment: @Thomas Ich habe mal gelernt, dass Fremdwörter und Eigennamen oft in lateinischer Schrift geschrieben wurden, von daher kann es gut sein, dass hier verschiedene *B* benutzt werden

Comment: "Bauerngutsbesitzer" scheind daselbst ein üblicher Stand gewesen zu sein: Siehe hoer: http://www.familie-berg-oberschlesien.de/karten-und-plaene-aus-heinersdorf-kreis-neisse-in-oberschlesien/

Comment: Da steht nicht  "Jungfer", sondern Tochter, oder?

Comment: Das erst "Jungfer" lese ich immer noch so, aber beim zweiten gehe ich mit - dann wird ihr Beruf/ihre Stellung zur Bauerngutsbesitzertochter :) Danke!

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help with this!  For clarification since some information may have been lost in translation... regarding the God parents:

Does this indicate or imply that Anna Winkler is Julius Hoffmann's daughter? Also, is there anything to indicate any association between Mrs Johanna Siegert and Julius Hoffmann (other than both being a God parent)?

Comment: @Carolyn No. IMHO there is no indication that neither Anna Winkler nor Johanna Siegert are in a relationship to Julius Hoffmann.

Comment: @Arsak Ich würde bei der zweiten Patin das fehlende Wort als "Stellanbstz." entziffern - allerdings habe ich keine Idee, was das heißen könnte.